# Invalid input value while using char and scanf "%hhu"

Tags: c, input, char, scanf

So this is the code

```
void main()
{
  unsigned char n,t;
  scanf("%hhu %hhu",&n,&t);
  printf("%hhu %hhu",n,t);
}
```

The problem is when I input 5 and 1 respectively, the output is 0 and 1. 0 for *n* and 1 for *t*. However, when I changed the type from char to int/unsigned, the output is right as expected: 5 and 1.

The question is why asking for (number) input with char gives invalid value?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? `scanf` is expecting `unsigned char*` with these formatting strings, is this intended?

Comment: example program does not give the incorrect output you describe for me ( gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 )

Comment: May I ask which on platfrom you experience this behaviour?

Comment: @bash.d (CMIIW) In addition to store a character, _char_ can be used to save 1 byte of number (-127..128 or 0..255) right? I'm just trying it for fun, and then I'm curious about the error

Comment: Alright! There you go

Comment: @Vorsprung Windows 7 x64 Codeblocks 12.11 (GCC 4.7.1) http://i.imgur.com/TldzKaX.png

Comment: @Alk Windows 7 x64 Codeblocks 12.11 (GCC 4.7.1) http://i.imgur.com/TldzKaX.png

Comment: This might answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15825386/694576

Answer (score 3):

`int main(void)` please

```
scanf("%hhu %hhu",&n,&t);
```

here  ---------- ^ ------^  `unsigned char *` is expected

same for `printf("%hhu %hhu",n,t);`

so change

```
char n,t;
```

to

`unsigned char n,t;`

Comment: The first line alone would have been enough to get my upvote ;-)

Comment: http://ideone.com/A38Ze5, In your picture you are still using main in a wrong way, and you don't include stdio

Comment: If it still doesn't work replace `printf("%hhu %hhu",n,t);` with `printf("%hhu %hhu\n",n,t);` (note the \n at the end)

Comment: @DavidRF Yes your code run as expected in ideone, but when I pasted your code to the codeblocks, it gives me same error. strange, but windows-related problem maybe?

Comment: @DavidRF it's no problem to not including stdio in C (not in C++) but yes I write bad codes, thanks for your tip

Answer (score 0):

Besides that it is

```
int main(void)
```

at least, you also might like to also add the necessary prototypes by including the appropriate header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```