# Stack around the variable was corrupted, after inputing unsigned char by scanf

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char y;
    scanf("%hhu", &y);
    printf("%hhu", y);
    return 0;
}
```

This code work's fine with g++ (Dev C++), but causes stack corruption in Visual Studio (2010), is this VS bug or there is any other way to input `unsigned char` in VS using `scanf();` ?

Comment: Why not use `cin` and save yourself the type non-safety headache?

Comment: Just choose one language: C **or** C++! Those are different languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is scanf("%hhu", char\*) overwriting other variables when they are local?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825254/why-is-scanfhhu-char-overwriting-other-variables-when-they-are-local)

Comment: @anatolyg: I disagree. The other question is about UB from accessing uninitialized locals mostly. VC not conforming to the standard is just a side-note.

Comment: If you are writing C code, you should use a C compiler, not C++. For a C++ program OTOH you should definitively use different code.

Comment: You could use with `unsigned u; unsigned char y; if (1 ==  scanf("%u", &u)) y = u;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like VS doesn't handle `%hhu`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825386/1715829

> The important detail is that you're using Windows, and presumably an outdated or non-conforming C environment (compiler and standard library). MSVCRT only supports C89 (and even then, not entirely correctly); in particular, there was no "hh" modifier in C89, and it's probably interpreting "hh" the same as "h" (i.e. short).

Comment: `Sounds like VS doesn't handle %hhu correctly`  More like "doesn't handle it at all", rather than "not correctly".  Handling it "not correctly" implies it *is* handled, but has bugs.

Comment: The linked question and answer show that MSVS treats `%hhu` like `%u`, that is, handles it incorrectly. You can say that it doesn't handle `hh` at all.

Comment: From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx): `The hh, j, z, and t length prefixes are not supported.`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit more detail...

The corruption occurs around line 1111 in input.c.

```
if ( integer64 )
  *(__int64 UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned __int64)num64;
else
if (longone)
  *(long UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned long)number;
else
  *(short UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned short)number;
```

You can see that there is no case where only 8 bits will be written.

While parsing the format string the counter `longone` initially has the value 1, and is decremented each time a 'h' character is encountered. Later on (at the above snippet) `longone` is used as a flag to determine if the parsed integer is 32 bits or not.

This behaviour is ok if `"%hu"` is used, as `longone` will be 0 and so the parsed value will be treated as 16 bits. If however `"%hhu"` is used, `longone` will be -1 and so the parsed value will be treated as 32 bits.

In either case (32 or 16 bit value) your supplied char pointer will have more than the expected 1 byte written, thus causing stack corruption.

This behaviour affects all `scanf()` related functions as Visual Studio implements things like `swscanf_s()` internally by making the input string look like a file handle. In this way everything ends up in the `_tinput_s_l()` function (line 368 in input.c) where the above problem manifests.

The [MSDN documentation for Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows the `%h` prefix but not the `%hh` prefix.

[What's new for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh409293.aspx) states that:

> C99 Conformance Visual Studio 2015 fully implements the C99 Standard
>   Library, with the exception of any library features that depend on
>   compiler features not yet supported by the Visual C++ compiler (for
>   example, `<tgmath.h>` is not implemented).

Which I read as "we've implemented everything, except the bits we haven't, which we won't tell you about."