# Unexpected behaviour while taking input in C language

Tags: c, char, printf

I am trying to run this code which seems fine to me but the end results are not much convincing. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char nT,nF;    
    char extension[5];

    puts("Enter No. of Testcases & Faults");
    scanf("%d %d %s", &nT, &nF, extension);
    printf("%d %d\n",nT,nF);
    getch();
}
```

Below is the sample input:

```
Enter No. of Testcases & Faults
50 50 code
```

Below is the output:

```
0 50
```

Below is the Expected output:

```
50 50
```

Note: I am bounded to use unsigned char and cannot use unsigned int.

I am using DevCpp 4.9.9.2. Please help if anyone has got the solution or the reason for why this is happening.

Comment: Undefined behavior for passing a pointer to the wrong type and of the wrong type to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Look into your `scanf` clause. You are passing two (pointers to) `unsigned char` variables to it, yet declare that you are reading two `ints` in your format specifier (`%d` specifier). Pass `%hhu` if you want to read `unsigned char`.

When you pass `&extension` to `scanf` there is no need to use ampersand. The name of the array gets converted to the pointer to its first element, so it's sufficient to pass just `extension`.

You are also using a very old IDE (Dev-C++), that is no longer developed. Probably the underlying compiler is dated as well. I advise to use newer tools, [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/) is actively developed, quite newbie-friendly and similar to Dev-C++ to a certain extent.

However, on Windows platforms, the MSVCRT library does not support the `%hhu` format specifier, as has been noted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825254/why-is-scanfhhu-char-overwriting-other-variables-when-they-are-local). MingGW compiler relies on this implementation, so it does not support `%hhu` on windows as well. [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) is a project that simulates Linux environment on Windows and is distributed with its own version of C library, that supports, among other things, `%hhu`. As a sidenote, you can configure Code::Blocks to work with Cygwin (as described [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Cygwin_Compiler)). I don't know if the same can be achieved with Dev-C++.

Comment: Using %hhu yields the same result as before. The problem is with compiler I suppose. What do you say? @lukeg

Comment: @Ankit Make sure your compiler version supports %hhu format specifier. I'd advise trying a newer one or trying to switch it into C99 mode. However, as you are on Windows, you might face another compatibility problem, see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825254/why-is-scanfhhu-char-overwriting-other-variables-when-they-are-local

Comment: I saw that question and I am facing the same problem. When I declare nT and nF as global variables, the output is as expected but the problem is with declaring them as local variables. This is a windows specific problem I suppose. Anyway thanks for the info :) @lukeg

Comment: @Ankit Yes, it's generally a Windows problem. I have just check that you can try using Cygwin (http://cygwin.org), which reimplements the standard Windows libraries and code runs fine there. I'll upate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int nT,nF;    
    char extension[5];

    puts("Enter No. of Testcases & Faults");
    scanf("%d %d %s", &nT, &nF, extension);
    printf("%d %d\n",nT,nF);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @dipika but I am bounded to use unsigned char and cannot use int

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char nT,nF;    
    char extension[5];

    puts("Enter No. of Testcases & Faults");
    scanf("%hhu %hhu %s", &nT, &nF, extension);
    printf("%hhu %hhu\n",nT,nF);
   // getch();
}
```

**You can see output on below image**

[image]

Comment: Is this code working on your machine for the above input?

Comment: It would be great if you test this code on windows platform because I am using windows :)

Comment: There could not be issue with platform. you can compile there and run it. Please upvote for answer.

Comment: There is an issue with the platform. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825254/why-is-scanfhhu-char-overwriting-other-variables-when-they-are-local